# Pandas adding multiple null data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create about 10 data frames with same number of rows and columns that I want to specify.
Currently I am creating a df with the specific rows and then using pd.concat to add column to the data frame. I am having to write 10 lines of code separately for each data frame. Is there a way to do it at one go together for all data frames. Say, all the data frames have 15 rows and 50 columns.
Also I don't want to use a loop. All values in the data frame are NaN and I want to perform different function on each data frame so editing one data frame shouldn't change the values of the other data frames.

Comment: pls post your code in your question, and also, try creating 10 variables and assign th same None DataFrame to all of it

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a numpy array of `np.nan`, and then create a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([15, 50])*np.nan)
```

For creating 10 dataframes, you can just run this in a loop and add it to an array.

```py
dfs = []
for i in range(10): 
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([15, 50])*np.nan))
```

Then you can index into `dfs` and change any value accordingly. It won't impact any other dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
index_list = range(10)
column_list = ['a','b','c','d']
for i in range(5):
   locals()["df_" + str(i)] = pd.DataFrame(index=index_list, columns=column_list)
```

This will create `5 different dataframes (df_1 to df_5)` each with `10 rows` and `4 columns named a,b,c,d` having all values as Nan

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

row_num = 15
col_num = 50
temp=[]

for col_name in range(0, col_num):
    temp.append(col_name)
```

Creation of Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,row_num), columns=temp)
```

this code creates a single data frame in pandas with specified row and column numbers. But without a loop or some form of iteration, multiple lines of same code must be written.

Note: this is a pure pandas implementation. [github gist can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/debodeepkar/4a9d0bdb8d2bf718ac9eee83f9cb8837)